# Scroll Position Restoration in AngularDart

Tags: angular, dart, angular-dart, angular-dart-routing

Is there an equivalent to `scrollPositionRestoration:` for routing in AngularDart?

If not how would I go about implementing that same behavior found in the Angular Docs:

```
class AppModule {
  constructor(router: Router, viewportScroller: ViewportScroller) {
    router.events.pipe(
      filter((e: Event): e is Scroll => e instanceof Scroll)
    ).subscribe(e => {
      if (e.position) {
        // backward navigation
        viewportScroller.scrollToPosition(e.position);
      } else if (e.anchor) {
        // anchor navigation
        viewportScroller.scrollToAnchor(e.anchor);
      } else {
        // forward navigation
        viewportScroller.scrollToPosition([0, 0]);
      }
    });
  }
}
```